# Issue using Tkinter. hiding labels, txtentry

Tags: python, tkinter

### What my code is supposed to do

There are two buttons, [one] and [two].
Clicking [one] should do this:

- def one and def graphOne
- Then, if you clicked on [two], it should remove everything that button [one] did (labels, entry text, etc.)
- Then def two and def graphTwo and keep switching between them whenever you click

### What my code is actually doing

Clicking on [one] does this:

- def one and def graphOne (This is right.)
- Then, if i clicked [two], it will pop a new window and it will not destroy the things that [one] did. It will just show def two and def graphTwo above them.

How can I fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle
tu=turtle

class App(Tk):
     def __init__(self):
         Tk.__init__(self)

         btnCupe=Button(self,text="one")
         btnCupe.grid(row=10,column=10)
         btnCupe["command"]=self.one

         btnTri=Button(self,text="two")
         btnTri.grid(row=10, column=12)
         btnTri["command"]=self.two


     def one(self):
         tu.clear()
         tu.pu()
         tu.home()
         tu.pd()
         Button(Tk(), text="Delete me", command=lambda: tri.destroy(self))
         Label(self,text="side").grid(row=1, column=0,)

         self.txtSide=Entry(self)
         self.txtSide.grid(row= 1, column= 1,columnspan=2)
         self.lblText = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "n", relief = "groove")
         self.lblText.grid(row=15, column= 0,rowspan=4,columnspan=3,sticky="ewns")

         btnCupe=Button(self,text="graph one")
         btnCupe.grid(row=12,column=10,columnspan=3)
         btnCupe["command"]=self.graphOne

     def graphOne(self):
         x=float(self.txtSide.get())
         tu.forward(x)

     def two(self):
         tu.clear()
         tu.pu()
         tu.home()
         tu.pd()
         Button(Tk(), text="Delete me", command=lambda: one.destroy(self))
         Label(self, text="First Side").grid(row=1, column=0,)

         self.txtFirst=Entry(self)
         self.txtFirst.grid(row= 1, column= 1,columnspan=2)

         self.lblText = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "n", relief = "groove")                  
         self.lblText.grid(row=15, column= 0,rowspan=4,columnspan=3,sticky="ewns")

         btnCupe=Button(self,text="graph two")
         btnCupe.grid(row=12,column=10,columnspan=3)
         btnCupe["command"]=self.graphTwo
     def graphTwo(self):
         first1=float(self.txtFirst.get())
         tu.forward(first1)



     def main():
         Graph=App()
         Graph.geometry("500x500")
         Graph.mainloop()                                                                             

if __name__== "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: Sorry, what was your question? What is your code doing, and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: What is my code suppose to do is: twos button [one] and [two]. clicking [one] should do: def one and def graphOne and THEN if you clicked on [two] it should remove everything that button [one] did(labels,entry txt,etc) then do def two and def graphTwo and keep switching between them whenever you click

what my code do is: clicking [one] do: def one and def graphOne #This is right and then if i clicked [two] it will pop a new window and it will not destroy the things that [one] did. it will just show def two and def graphtwo above them @yellowantphil

Comment: I edited your post, hopefully making it a bit easier to read. Feel free to edit it again if I messed something up, of course.